# Returning HEX for symbols

Tags: python, unicode, discord.py

I have a discord.py bot and currently using this code for the youtube command and returns the top 5 songs from Youtube

```
 for v in videolist:
    youtube  = etree.HTML(urlopen(v).read())
    video_title = youtube.xpath("//span[@id='eow-title']/@title")
    v_t = ''.join(video_title)
    vt.append(v_t)
  names = vt[1:6]
  await bot.say(vt)
```

This gets the video titles for all songs.

Now its not that this doesn't work but I get the following output(shortened

```
`['Yowamushi Pedal - Love Hime Opening [Full Song]', 'Koi no Hime Hime Pettankoã\x80\x8cæ\x81\x8bã\x81®ã\x83\x92ã\x83¡ã\x83\x92ã\x83¡ã\x81ºã\x81£ã\x81\x9fã\x82\x93ã\x81\x93ã\x80\x8dæ\xad\x8cã\x81£ã\x81¦ã\x81¿ã\x81\x9fã\x80\x90ï¼\x8aã\x81ªã\x81¿ã\x82\x8aã\x82\x93ã\x80\x91', '~ hime hime `:
```

If you didn't notice the encoding error/issue it is this junky looking stuff here: `\x81\x93ã\x80\x8dæ\xad\x8cã\x81£ã\x81¦ã\x81¿ã\x81\x9fã\x80\x90ï¼\x8`

How can I get python to return the proper symbols istead of this hexdecimal code?? Any information would be great and welcomed!

Comment: If you loop through `vt` and `say` each one individually, do you see the same output?

Comment: I will attempt this now and get back to you Patrick Haugh.

Comment: Which Python version are you using? There are important differences in Unicode handling between Python 2 & 3.

Comment: Python 3.6 as python 2 is not supported by discord.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the hex-values of the Japanese string encoded in UTF-8:

```
e3, 80, 8c, e6, 81, 8b, e3, 81, ae, e3, 83, 92, e3, 83, a1, e3, 83, 92, e3, 83, a1, e3, 81, ba, e3, 81, a3, e3, 81, 9f, e3, 82, 93, e3, 81, 93, e3, 80, 8d, e6, ad, 8c, e3, 81, a3, e3, 81, a6, e3, 81, bf, e3, 81, 9f, e3, 80, 90, ef, bc, 8a, e3, 81, aa, e3, 81, bf, e3, 82, 8a, e3, 82, 93, e3, 80, 91
```

If you squint your eyes a little, you can see the "junky looking stuff" in there.

The "default fix" seems to work just fine, namely re-encoding from ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8:

For this input:

```
s = 'Koi no Hime Hime Pettankoã\x80\x8cæ\x81\x8bã\x81®ã\x83\x92ã\x83¡ã\x83\x92ã\x83¡ã\x81ºã\x81£ã\x81\x9fã\x82\x93ã\x81\x93ã\x80\x8dæ\xad\x8cã\x81£ã\x81¦ã\x81¿ã\x81\x9fã\x80\x90ï¼\x8aã\x81ªã\x81¿ã\x82\x8aã\x82\x93ã\x80\x91'
```

This code:

```
s.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
```

produces this output:

```
'Koi no Hime Hime Pettanko「恋のヒメヒメぺったんこ」歌ってみた【＊なみりん】'
```

I'm not sure what your bot is doing, but it gets the text in the default ISO 8859-1 encoding instead of decoding UTF-8 properly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried converting to Unicode implicitly?
For example:

```
    a = u"[狂おしく咲いた凄惨な骸は奏で、愛おしく裂いた少女は聖餐の詞を謳う。 #10] 謳"
```

This makes the string Unicode supported and might fix your issue

Comment: I could use this but I would have to individually get each single Unicode character  to correct the issues wouldn't I?

Comment: After all its not just a japanese character that could appear, it could be german, french, russian etc. Though this method would work it doesn't fit the over all needs I have.

Comment: How about just making it Unicode from the start? doing `fu"{video_title = youtube.xpath("//span[@id='eow-title']/@title")}"` might work

Comment: @TylerT that will raise a syntax error to say the least, as you can’t use assignment in f-strings and the quotations will confuse the interpreter. To OP: I would suggest you to use a list comp and follow Andrey’s solution. Since you cannot just “add” a little `u` in front of pre-existing strings (ie. obtained from `xpath(...)`), you need to explicitly encode it.